# Sinon spy callCount property returns 0 on some tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

This is my code:

```js
// SUT.spec.js
import * as myModule from './myModule';

describe('my issue', () => {
  let myFuncSpy = sinon.spy(myModule, 'myFunc');

  beforeEach(() => {
    myFuncSpy.reset();
  });

  it('my case A', () => {
    SUT.methodA();

    expect(myFuncSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);  // fails, it says it's 0
  });

  it('my case B', () => {
    SUT.methodB();

    expect(myFuncSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);  // passes

  });
});
```

In my module, both method calls `myFunc`, however only on `methodA` it's not being registered:

```js
// SUT.js
import { myFunc } from './myModule';

export function methodA() {
  myFunc(....);
  console.log(myFunc.callCount); // Mocha output shows 1
};

export function methodB() {
  myFunc(....);
  console.log('method B ran');   // Mocha output shows this line
  console.log(myFunc.callCount); // Mocha output shows 1
};
```

Basically there is no apparent difference in the way the spy is being called. I'm very confused as what could be possible wrong.

I added the `console.log` statement inside the SUT just to make sure the spy was properly set (otherwise it wouldn't have a property called `callCount`).  Also, if I comment out the `.reset()` call, the log statement shows `undefined` instead of `1` or another number.

What could be wrong in here?  This is of course a simplified version of the actual SUT. However, the `console.log` statements show that the problem is definitely not that the lines are not being executed.

Comment: are you doing anything async in methodA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to await your asynchronous methods before asserting.